# Parameter list with double quotes does not pass through properly in Bash

Tags: string, bash

I have a Bash script that calls another Bash script. The called script does some modification and checking on a few things, shifts, and then passes the rest of the caller's command line through.

In the called script, I have verified that I have everything managed and ready to call. Here's some debug-style code I've put in:

```
echo $SVN $command $@ > /tmp/shimcmd
bash /tmp/shimcmd
$SVN $command $@
```

Now, in /tmp/shimcmd you'll see:

```
svn commit --username=myuser --password=mypass --non-interactive --trust-server-cert -m "Auto Update autocommit Wed Apr 11 17:33:37 CDT 2012"
```

That is, the built command, all on one line, perfectly fine, including a -m "my string with spaces" portion.

It's perfect. And the "bash /tmp/shimcmd" execution of it works perfectly as well.

But of course I don't want this silly tmp file and such (only used it to debug). The problem is that calling the command directly, instead of via the shim file:

```
$SVN $command $@
```

results in the svn command itself NOT receiving the quoted string with spaces--it garbles the '-m "my string with spaces"' parameter and shanks the command as if it was passed as '-m my string with spaces'.

I have tried all manner of crazy escape methods to no avail. Can't believe it's dogging me this badly. Again, by echoing the very same thing ($SVN $command $@) to a file and then executing that file, it's FINE. But calling directly garbles the quoted string. That element alone shanks.

Any ideas?

Dan

Comment: Can you post some exact steps to get this behaviour? I'm having trouble reproducing the problem.

Comment: @jimw it's a very common antipattern -- basically, you can't count on string-splitting to do the right thing; he should be using arrays instead.

Comment: Very true. Usually I can tease out these quoting problems by fiddling, but you're absolutely right if we're talking about good programming practice. I must admit, when I get to the point of needing arrays in my bash script, I usually turn to perl or python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
eval "$SVN $command $@"
```

?

Comment: Presto! simply adding "eval" : eval "$SVN $command $@" did the trick. Works just right! Thanks very much for all the ideas--will go with the simple eval to git-er-done for now.

Comment: @user1327769 PLEASE DO NOT DO THIS. Using eval is seriously insecure if dealing with untrusted inputs, whereas using arrays handles these cases safely. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048

Comment: The above works in any POSIX-conforming shell. The basic idea of this problem is that a command stored across various variables is to be run. If you do not trust the contents of that command, then this whole approach is wrongheaded. E.g. if someone could manipulate `$SVN` so that it does `rm -rf /` (and you are root) then avoiding eval won't help you.

Comment: This particular script is in a well-controlled, unattended, automated environment that does not interact with any users or user input. That said, sure, it's not without risk but the risk level is low.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to demonstrate the problem:

```
$ args='-m "foo bar"'
$ printf '<%s> ' $args
<-m> <"foo> <bar">
```

And here's a way to avoid it:

```
$ args=( -m "foo bar" )
$ printf '<%s> ' "${args[@]}"
<-m> <foo bar>
```

In this latter case, args is an array, not a quoted string.

Note, by the way, that it has to be `"$@"`, not `$@`, to get this behavior (in which string-splitting is avoided in favor of respecting the array entries' boundaries).

Answer (score 0):

this

```
echo -n -e  $SVN \"$command\"  > /tmp/shimcmd
for x in "$@"
  do
     a=$a" "\"$x\"
  done
echo -e " " $a >> /tmp/shimcmd
bash /tmp/shimcmd
```

or simply

```
$SVN "$command" "$@"
```

Comment: If you wanted to safely escape a string, `printf %q` is the canonical way, rather than writing a mess of spaghetti like this.

Comment: Sure, for values of "canonical" not equal to "portable" or "POSIX standard". It may be a convenient way, or a GNU-y way, but canonical is somewhat of a loaded word.